# gcc-4.4.0-1aix5.3 missing dependency libgmp, libmpfr

Tags: gcc, aix, rpm, gcc4

I am trying to install gcc-4.4.0-1 on Aix 5.3 system(64 BIT). I have installed MPFR 2.0 and LIBGMP 4.3 and can see libgmp.a and libmpfr.a in /usr/lib. I also used --enable-shared option and can see libgmp.so.3 and libmpfr.so.4 in /usr/lib. LIBPATH conatins /usr/lib.

Still , I am stuck for hours with below error:-

```
rpm -ivh gcc-4.4.0-1.aix5.3.ppc.rpm
error: failed dependencies:
libgmp.a(libgmp.so.3) is needed by gcc-4.4.0-1
libmpfr.a(libmpfr.so.1) is needed by gcc-4.4.0-1
```

Can anybody plz point as to what the issue is and what steps do I need to take?

Comment: did you install rpms or from scratch?

Comment: I used rpms from GNU resource links - "http://gnome.bullfreeware.com/aixtoolbox/RPMS/ppc/gcc/" . I was able to install gcc 4.0.0 successfully. But , I am stuck with gcc-4.4.0

Comment: no, the gmp and mpfr, are they from rpms?

Comment: No, I built them from scratch. I got the source from official sites.

Comment: try `rpm -ivv --nodeps `

Comment: I tried that and gcc script failed. After that as soon as I type in gcc, it says "cannot load program gcc because of following erros"

Comment: do you have /usr/lib64 directory?

Comment: No .. I have /usr/lib, /lib, /usr/local/lib

Comment: try to put it there and try rpm again

Comment: I just did the same step you mentioned and am still getting same error...Though, I very much apprecciate your help

Comment: cant help betond this, sry.  try building gcc from scratch if all else fails.

Comment: Is there a way to force rpm to look for dependenct libs in other directories..

Comment: not sure.  hey, is your libgmp.so.3 64 or 32 bits?  i think aix defaults to 32.  try `file `

Comment: libgmp.so.3: executable (RISC System/6000) or object module not stripped

Comment: I have never had much success with file command on AIX i.e not seen 32 or 64 bit as in other platforms

Comment: bummer, try to rebuild maybe with 'xlc -q64` or `gcc -m64`?

Comment: Thats the cyclic issue...Do you mean to say build mpfr/libgmp with gcc 4.0.0 using "gcc -m64"...I guess-"configure.sh" for both libraries should have some setting  for 32/64

Comment: sure.  if you use ./configure, try adding CFLAGS=-m64

Comment: hey, i am gonna go away, will check later if i can still give any ideas, ok?

Comment: maybe also try `CFLAGS=-m32`, i dont know what gcc defaults to on AIX.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem.
I installed the gmp and mpfr rpms and it solved it.

Answer (score -1):

install gmp-devel & mpfr-devel

Comment: Not so helpfull, clearly user is in trouble with installing those packages, give more insight or ask for more details